# How to configure a shared log folder with non-read access for other users files?

Tags: c#, windows, logging, permissions, directory

I have a c# application deployed to thousands of machines that writes log files to a shared log folder on a Windows server, e.g. "M:\VSDRW00121\Logs\MyApplication". The log files have the file name [MACHINE_NAME]_[USER_NAME].log so that multiple users can write their log files there.

Is there a way to configure so that a user can not read/delete/modify log files from other users on this Windows server (I assume there is)? Maybe my application will simply have to set the permissions programmatically when the log file is created so that no other users can read or edit the file or maybe this can be configured on a folder level configuration somehow?

In an ideal world, I would also like to prevent the user himself/herself from modifying his/her own log file as it is there for compliance reasons. But I am not sure if this is possible right? As the application will need to have write access to actually create and write the log file with new data?

Many thanks in advance if you have the chance to help me with this.

Comment: Not modifying but writing to it? Sounds like a contrast. Setting permissions on folder level won't work. The application may need to set it on file level. Possiblity to assure compliance is to add a checksum/hash or completely encrypt it. Or use a complete different approach: Use a database to make the loggings.

Comment: Why not using a different account with write permission on the log folder and deny access to this folder to everyone else? Do you really need end users reading their own log files?

Comment: Yes "Not modifying but writing to it?" but that is only the second part of the question which I understand might not be possible. For setting the file permissions, I as a owner of the file can set them so that no other non-admin user will be able to read or copy the files?

Comment: MarkusEgle: Yes, communicating with a webservice on a central database might be the best option. 

Oscar: The application is running with the user's Windows permission and that cannot be changed.